# how to avoid duplicated endpoints in Spring Boot to support Hateoas?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I've been implementing [Spring Hateoas](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) the latter time but i noticed that i was  doing boilerplate code everywhere to support both formats: `application/json` and `application/hal+json`. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", method = GET, produces = {application/hal+json})
public ResponseEntity<UserResourceDTO> getUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId) {
     User user = this.userService.getUser(userId);
     UserResourceDTO userResourceDTO = this.mapper.map(user, UserResourceDTO.class);
     linkTo(methodOn(UserController.class).getUser(userId)).withSelfRel();
     linkTo(methodOn(UserAuthorityController.class).getUserAuthorities(userId)).withRel("authorities");
     return new ResponseEntity<UserResourceDTO>(userResourceDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{userId}", method = GET, produces = {application/json})
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId) {
     User user = this.userService.getUser(userId);
     UserDTO userDTO = this.mapper.map(user, UserDTO.class);
     return new ResponseEntity<UserDTO>(userDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

One thing to notice is that `UserResourceDTO` and `UserDTO` cannot be the same object since the first one is a `Resource` and doesn't have ID, unlike the second one which also doesn't support links for not being a resource.

That is just a short example, but just imagine the amount of duplicated code that would be to support both `Content-Types`. I know if i use default [Spring Data Rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) controllers then i wouldn't have this boilerplate code problem, but i want to do this with custom ones.

Anyways, i basically want to have a unique `UserDTO` annotated with relations and also has ID, something like

```
@Relation(value = "some link reference", rel = "authorities")
@Relation(value = "some link reference", rel = "self")
public class UserResponseDTO { 

     private String id;
     private String username;
     private String email;

     // Getters and setters
}
```

This way, if user sends header "Accept: application/json" i return json response with ids and if it sends header "Accept: application/hal+json" then i use annotations to build relations (with a custom MessageConverter maybe?)

I've seen things like using [RelProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/0.19.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#spis.rel-provider) to load `@Relation` (different one what is being used in the above example) annotations which is probably what i am looking for but i couldn't make that work (maybe because i didn't find examples for that)

Is it possible what i am asking for? Is there something offered by `Spring` out of the box to reach this?

Comment: Note that you can use `org.springframework.hateoas.Resource` to wrap an object into a resource. With this you can get rid of `UserResourceDTO`.

Comment: Yes,  that way I would probably avoid duplicated links,  but I the only difference in this case is that I would use resource assembler instead of inserting links manually.  I would still have two different methods.  Thanks eitherway